# Bug in gvim - where to report?

Tags: vim

I recently encountered a bug in gvim's (that is the gui for vim) syntax highlighting for LaTeX which can be reproduced on several platforms (packages vim-gtk in debian/ubuntu and mvim for MacOS X) but not in command line vim. I wonder what is the right place to report this issue?

Answer (score 10):

Start Vim and execute:

```
:help bugs
```

Comment: @ib. I suggest that for one-off purposes and the given audience, `:help bugs` is far superior to the minimum abbreviation. This is not about golf, or workflow optimization

Comment: @sehe:  I tried to convey the spirit of the original answer and leave the shortened command.  My edit just suggests:  If you like to shorten a command, it is better to use the most common shortcut (the one proposed in Vim help).

Comment: @ib. okay, I get the logic. I just think it is contrived :) My _point_ was about readability. In that respect I think `:help` > `:he` > `:h`. Just a friendly note - I think you are awesome [tag:vim] so, keep up the good work.

Comment: @sehe:  I agree about readability.  (In my own answers I almost always refer to the `:help` command in its full form.)  Probably the author should expand the command (or add some description), so that its intent would be clear.  By the way, thanks for your notes.  They are always useful!

Answer (score 4):

The GUI version of Vim has more highlighting attributes (and available colors) than console Vim; maybe that's why the bug only manifests itself in the GUI version. If you think this is a problem with the syntax definition, contact the maintainer of the syntax, found in the header of `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim`. Chip Campbell often also has newer beta versions of his plugins on his site, try them out.

On the other hand, for reporting a bug against Vim, it would be best to reduce it to a minimal set of `:syntax` and `:highlight` commands, and then following the instructions at `:help bugs`.